# Error with publishing package using npm-registry-client

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to use the npm-registry-client - https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-registry-client when trying to copy package from one feed to another.

However, I am getting error when trying to publish to the target registry.

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Array     at Hash.update (internal/crypto/hash.js:82:11)

Prior to publishing, I fetch the package using the same module.  The fetch succeeds and returns 200.  Then I pass the resolved data to the publish function.

```
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                client.fetch(dist.tarball, from.params,
                    function process(error, data, raw, res) {
                        if (error) {
                            reject(error);
                        }
                        resolve(data);
                    }
                );
            })
            .then(tarball => {
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    publishParams = {
                        metadata: newMetadata,
                        access: "public",
                        body: tarball,
                        auth: to.params.auth
                    }
                    npm.publish(`${to.feedUrl}/${moduleName}`, publishParams, process(error, data, raw, res) {});
```

.......

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was getting a 302 and use the redirection tarball for fetching the tarball.

1. I changed to node-fetch up to the fetching of the tarball (to minimize the callbacks and just use async/await).
2. I still used npm-registry-client for the actual publishing